# How do you split an integer in java?

Tags: java

I have tried making the integer into a string then splitting it like that but then I get an error because I have to multiply that number that is a string but obviously I can't. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI {
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner BMI1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner BMI2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner BMI3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int weightPounds;
    int heightFtInches;
    int heightInches;
    double weightKg;
    double heightM;

    System.out.print("Please enter your name (e.g. First Last): ");
    name = BMI1.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter your weight in pounds (e.g. 150): ");
    weightPounds = BMI2.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter your height in feet and inches (e.g. 6, 8): ");
    heightFtInches = BMI3.nextLine();
    String[] token = heightFtInches.split(",");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Body Mass Index Calculator");
    System.out.println("#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#");
    System.out.println();

    weightKg = weightPounds / 2.2;
    heightInches = heightFtInches * 12;


    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Weight in Kg: " + weightKg);
    System.out.println("Height in meters: " + heightInches);
 }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to achieve, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Well he almost did, but it's confusing without a minimal example. We don't need to see any of this BMI stuff.

Comment: Shows us what you have and what you want.

Comment: I have to convert the height the user inputs which is in ft and inches then I have to convert that into meters and then use the weight and height given and calculate their body mass index.

Comment: You only need and only should have one Scanner object for this current project. There will be times when you will need more than one, but they won't all be scanning the same input (here System.in). Get rid of  BMI2 and BMI3. Also learn and use Java naming conventions so you don't confuse us with your code. Variables names, such as your Scanner variable as well as method names should start with a lower-case letter while class names should start with an upper case letter. I'd name my Scanner variable, scanner. It's clear, to the point, and describes what it is.

Comment: So you're completely dependent on your user entering their data using the correct format? I don't think that's going to end well, certainly not without some error handling.

Comment: System.out.print("Please enter your height in feet and inches separated with a space: ");
    height = BMI3.nextInt();     feet = BMI3.nextInt();

Comment: First off, this is what my teacher asked me to do and what the system is outputting, is what she asked me to have the system output and I use multiple scanners because it avoids confusion for me and I am not confusing you with my code. if you don't like how it's written don't look at it.

Comment: @Nate, don't take comments here quite so personally. They are intended to help you out, even beyond what you are learning immediately in this particular assignment.  You're posting code publicly, and more experienced developers are taking time to provide you w/their thoughts and experience :)

Comment: You are right. I am sorry and I know they are trying to help but I am only in my second month of java programming in my school but thank you everyone for helping me. I managed to convert the feet and inches to inches then to meters.

Comment: @Nate - I remember that stress well, even though it was over 13 years ago :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method can be used to read the values for `feet` and `weight`. The method will use a space as a delimiter even if the values are entered simultaneously:

```
int feet = bmi1.nextInt();
int height = bmi1.nextInt();
```

Comment: OP is already using nextInt() for int weightPounds.

Comment: No reason why they they can't be used again for reading the `feet` & `height`. -updated

Comment: I know, I was just clarifying that OP new that this method existed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you split the String and don't use it (well after you change `heightFtInches` to a String)

```
String[] token = heightFtInches.split(",");
```

What you want is to convert each into an int (Note this is assuming valid input)

```
int feet = Integer.parseInt(token[0]);
int inches = Integer.parseInt(token[1]);
```

Then you can mutliple `feet` and `inches` by the correct equatiob to get metric height

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] token = heightFtInches.split(",");
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Body Mass Index Calculator");
System.out.println("#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#");
System.out.println();

weightKg = weightPounds / 2.2;
heightInches = heightFtInches * 12;
```

Your height in feet is now in `token[0]` so I assume you are looking for something like this:

```
heightInches = (Integer.parseInt(token[0]) * 12) + Integer.parseInt(token[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous two answers, you have declared `heightFtInches` as an `int` but I think it should be a `String` so you can use the `split()` method on it.

Comment: I have to multiply this integer though so thats why I can't make it a string.

Comment: Yes, but then you would use `Integer.parseInt( token[0] );` to convert one value and then the other (with `Integer.parseInt( token[1] );`) and you will be able to do arithmetic with the resulting `int`s..